# IO Completion Ports and socket send()

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, iocp

Based on my understanding so far of IOCP, when I create a completion port and associate a socket to it, a notification will be sent to the completion port when a socket is ready to be read.

But how `send()` is handled, I mean if I want to send data, should I just call `send()`? what about the completion port, does it get any notification regarding `send()`?

Comment: With IOCP, it's usual to use overlapped I/O with WSASend/WASRecv to queue up I/O requests.  Using send() does not take advantage of IOCP and cannot initiate overlapped I/O requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Based on my understanding so far of IOCP, when I create a completion
>   port and associate a socket to it, a notification will be sent to the
>   completion port when a socket is ready to be read.

NO!  One advantage of the IOCP mechanism is that you can queue up read/write requests, with associated buffers, to the kernel and have a kernel threadpool perform the IO operations in kernel state.  It's an I/O COMPLETION port, ie. you are notified upon operation completed.

If it's a read, you get your buffer, (pointer), back with the data already loaded - you don't have to explicitly read/copy it again.

If it's a write, the data has already gone and your returned buffer, (pointer). is free to be deleted/reused/repooled/whatever.

Comment: But isn't this question says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644276/io-completion-ports-and-socket-recv

Comment: I mean when I associate a socket with a completion port, and I want to read, should I call 'recv()'?

Comment: @user4582812 - the answer given, (and accepted), is not relevant to IOCP at all - it is not an answer.

Comment: No. Calling recv() is not appropriate for IOCP.  You do not need to read upon I/O completion notification because the read operation has already been completed when you receive notification - your buffer is already loaded with received data.

Comment: OK, so after I associate my socket to the completion port, I call WASRecv() (which I think holds my buffer?), and then when I receive a notification, the notification just indicated that the data were read into the buffer I supplied?

Comment: @user4582812 - OK, now you're getting it:)